# Get the NAS drive information

Tags: powershell

I wanted to get the details of NAS drive like the owner, access, path etc. using below command, however, it's not giving what I expected to get:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | %{$_.Root }
A:\
C:\
D:\
Y:\
Z:\

When I run only first part of the command like below..
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                               ---------------
A                                      FileSystem    A:\
C                  26.82         23.18 FileSystem    C:\                                     Users\sa-its-sd-na-vco2d-d
D                    .03          9.96 FileSystem    D:\
Y                 112.84        137.16 FileSystem    \\exmaple.hac.com\opp$
Z                                      FileSystem    Z:\
```

my intention was to get `\\exmaple.hac.com\opp$` but not getting it. Any idea how to fetch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, taht you are using `Root` but you want `DisplayRoot`.

I think you can use the `select` also:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select DisplayRoot
```

will output something like:

```
A:\
C:\                   
D:\
\\exmaple.hac.com\opp$
Z:\
```

this will just select the Root column. If you want more, for example Name and DisplayRoot:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select Name,Root
```